# Making a negative trait in Rust, opposite of Sized (Unsized)

Tags: rust, traits

I've figured i need a trait which is the opposite of `Sized`. Anything which is not `Sized` should have this trait. I need this in order to avoid conflicting implementation when specializing another trait elsewhere in my code differently for sized and non-sized types. Using `?Sized` in this case does not work as it leads to conflicting implementations.

For this i've defined an auto-trait, and then made a negative impl for `T` in the cases where `T: Sized`.

I'm using rust-nightly with features `auto_traits` and `negative_impls` turned on in `main.rs`:

```
#![feature(auto_traits)]
#![feature(negative_impls)]
```

For some reason `dyn Any` does not implement `Unsized`, despite also not implementing `Sized`. Is there some implicit `Sized` requirement in the auto implementation or something? Ideally i'd want every type to either extend `Sized`, or `Unsized` with no overlap.

```rust
use std::any::Any;

use static_assertions::assert_impl_one;

pub auto trait Unsized {}

impl<T> !Unsized for T
where
    T: Sized
{
    
}

assert_not_impl_any!(dyn Any: Sized); // Succeeds! -> dyn Any is not Sized, as expected.
assert_impl_one!(dyn Any: Unsized); // Fails! -> dyn Any is not Unsized either??? It should be.
```

Why does the trait `Unsized` not get implemented for things which are obviously not `Sized`?

Removing the negative implementation yields the same assertion results. `dyn Any` is still not `Unsized`.

Comment: I don't know anything about the details of those two features, but `dyn Any` is `?Sized`, which intuitively would suggest to me that it's either both `Sized` and `Unsized` or neither, the latter of which would fit the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Even if you will be able to construct such trait, this won't help you as rustc is unable to reason about such specialization.

Comment: You can specialize on `Sized`, though (even with `min_specialization`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto-traits are not implemented for dyn Traits, unless they explicitly opt them in (`dyn Any + Sync`, `dyn Any + Unsized`).

The reason is that auto traits have little value if we consider the `dyn Trait` itself, as it has no information about the actual type. Usually, what we want is that the underlying type implements the auto-trait, not the `dyn Trait` itself. Think about `Sync`, for example: we cannot tell if `dyn Any` is `Sync` or not, because we don't know what data it contains. Only the actual type can be `Sync` or not. That is why `dyn Trait` never implement an auto trait, unless the user explicitly say it will bring only types that implement it (`dyn Trait + AutoTrait`).

Comment: I see. Thanks. I suppose it doesn't make sense if you assume that structs always have the same traits + more than the trait object. However i know that it is possible to implement traits uniqely for the trait-object and not the underlying structs if you do it manually. For instance:
```
trait Something {}

trait SomethingDynamic {}

impl SomethingDynamic for dyn Something {}

struct Thing {}

impl Something for Thing {}

assert_not_impl_any!(Thing: SomethingDynamic);
assert_impl_all!(dyn Something: SomethingDynamic);
```

Comment: @sigurd4 That's true, but auto-traits don't work that way.